# Spring Security combine Container Security and JWT Token

Tags: spring-security, jwt

Is it possible to have a login rest service that authenticates with Spring Security the container security and if successful then returns a JWT Token.  Call to other services then would use JWT Filter.

The basic idea is this.

1. I have React Application that has a login Page.  It sends a login request (via rest service) with username and password.  The security is container based (an example would be Tomcat users).  Spring security should authenticate via container and if the username and password are ok, then the login service returns a JWT Token.
2. All other services use Spring Security JWT Token Filter security.

I can't find examples of this situation when I google.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to find is what Spring Security calls [Pre-Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-preauth).

You can enable it for different scenarios, I will show an example Java EE container.

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain appSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        ...
        .jee(Customizer.withDefaults())
        ...

    return http.build();
}
```

What the `jee()` will do is registering a `J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` in your `SecurityFilterChain`, and the filter itself will extract the `Principal` from the `HttpServletRequest` and call the `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` to authenticate it.

Then, in your controller, you can inject the `Principal` and build the JWT using the Principal's details.

Comment: Thanks, getting very close. Still not completely working.  Here is what I have: in my Springboot application properties I have spring.security.user.name=testuser
spring.security.user.password=testpwd  I then send the request via Insomnia, Basic Auth.  I go into the debugger from J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.  The header has authorization with value of Basic dGVzdHVzZXI6dGVzdHB3ZA==  However it returns a principal of null.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question anymore then. Are you trying to authenticate using HTTP Basic using your own user store, or are you trying to use Servlet-based pre-authentication?

Comment: I have a tomcat server and currently use tomcat-users.xml.  End customers will setup the user connection (LDAP) within Tomcat settings.  So it is server based authentication.  I have a login rest service that sends the username and password.  From what I understood is that PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider would authenticate against the server.  First question is this a correct understanding?  What happens is that the Principle is always null.  Maybe the problem is how I am sending the username and password in the request.  Maybe you could give me some guidance.  Thanks so much!

Comment: You have to know how the user is coming to the application. Take a look at the reference guide and the `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` implementations. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-preauth